# matplotlib legend shows "Container object of 10 artists" instead of label

Tags: matplotlib, legend

The code below produces the plot and legend correctly, however the legend does not show the specified `label` text, but "Container object of 10 artists" instead.

```
ax = plt.subplot(212)

plt.tight_layout()

l1= plt.bar(X+0.25, Y1, 0.45, align='center', color='r', label='A', edgecolor='black', hatch="/")
l2= plt.bar(X,      Y2, 0.45, align='center', color='b', label='N',hatch='o', fill=False)

ax.autoscale(tight=True)

plt.xticks(X, X_values)

ymax1 = max(Y1) + 1
ymax2 = max(Y2) + 1

ymax = max(ymax1,ymax2)+1
plt.ylim(0, ymax)

plt.grid(True)

plt.legend([l1,l2], loc='upper right', prop={'size':20})
```

The output is shown below:

[image: Plot showing the missing labels]

How can I correctly display the labels for each bar (as specified in the `plt.bar()` function) on the legend?

Comment: Can you add your data (the lines before the included code) as it makes it a lot easier to replicate your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from mixing two approaches to using `plt.legend()`. You have two options:

1. Manually specify the labels for the legend
2. Use `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to fill them in with the `label` parameters you passed to `plt.bar()`

To manually specify the labels, pass them as the second argument to your call to `plt.legend()` as follows:

```
plt.legend([l1,l2], ["A", "N"], loc='upper right', prop={'size':20})
```

If instead you want to automatically populate the legend you can use the following to find legend-able objects in the plot and their labels:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right', prop={'size':20})
```